# How to find the date number given the Year, month, day of the week and the week it falls on in ruby

Tags: ruby, date

So i'm new to ruby and not to familiar with the syntax of the Date gem, but is there a way to find the date of a moving holiday like fathers day?

So my current class for the moving holidays looks like this:

```
class MovingHoliday < Holiday
    def initialize (name, month, day_of_week, week, year=2016)
        @name = name
        @month = month
        @day_of_week = day_of_week
        @week = week
        @year = year
        @my_date = Date.new(year, month, day)
    end  
end
```

and my input looks like this:

```
fathers_day = MovingHoliday.new("Fathers Day", 6, "sunday", 4, year)
```

The 6 is the month, "sunday" is well the day_of_the_week, and 4 is the week it falls on.
I just can't figure out the syntax if there is any that would/could do conversion for this.
And I can't use any gems other then rubys Date.

Comment: You mean the Ruby core [Date library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)?

Comment: I think you mean `@my_date =`?  Otherwise, `my_date` is a local variable that will be lost when the method finishes.

Comment: Yeah, your right thanks. ^fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MovingHoliday < Holiday
    def initialize (name, month, day_of_week, week, year=2016)
        @name = name
        @month = month
        @day_of_week = day_of_week
        @week = week
        @year = year
        @my_date = Date.new(year, month, 1)
        @my_date += 1 while !my_date.send("#{day_of_week}?")
        @my_date += (7 * (week - 1))
    end  
end
```

Not pretty, but it works. It takes the first of the month, moves up a day until it's the correct day of the week, and then increases by the appropriate number of weeks.

As it stands, it assumes that you're given an actual day of the week. You'll probably want to sanitize the input in some manner or convert from "sunday" to 0 (my_date.wday returns 0 for sunday, 1 for monday, etc)

Comment: I recommend extracting that computation into a separate method.

Comment: Agreed. This is more for the concept. It doesn't even store the result anywhere before the method terminates

Comment: Ok! but one question is what does the whoe `!x.send` do?

Comment: "#{day_of_week}?" becomes the string "sunday?". sunday? is a method on date objects that returns a boolean whether or not the date is a sunday. The send method of any object takes in a string (or symbol) and calls that method on the object. So I'm getting the string "sunday?" and calling the sunday? method on the date object

Comment: oh whoops, just realized I had it as x.send and not my_date.send. Fixed

Comment: I'd be tempted to do calculations based on `cweek` of 1st in month, then produce the date with `Date.commercial`, but this solution seems more straight-forward.
I would recommend using the [Holidays](https://github.com/holidays/holidays) gem, though.

Comment: OHH, that actually makes a lot of sense now, so the Date library has a check method for each day of the week. So the way I'm seeing it is that it will count up by one until the Boolean expression is true then it will multiply   seven by the number of weeks minus the first since it was used to find the day. right?

Answer (score 1):

`date` in Ruby is not a gem, it's part of the standard library, it's just not loaded unless you `require` it.  (In Ruby, `require` is used for both purposes, loading gems and loading parts of the standard library that are not loaded by default.)

I don't know of any built-in functionality that would calculate the date for you, I think you'd have to write that yourself, since you don't want to consider other gems.